# How to find an old Soviet physics paper?

Tags: particle-physics, specific-reference

I am interested in an old physics paper by [Viktor Ambartsumyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Hambardzumyan) and [Dmitrii Ivanenko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmitri_Ivanenko): [Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Doklady-Akademii-Nauk-SSSR/107915375923665?nr=137876372891802), ser. A, No. 6, p.153 (1930). It concerns the structure of the atomic nucleus and accurately predicted the neutron's existence. I have been unable to locate it online.

Comment: Inter-library loan. You local university library participates and it lets them get things in from the damndest places. Of course that mean the lead time can be considerable, but it is worth initiating a ILL request while you continue to scour the internet and other sources.

Comment: Another related article is: http://www.springerlink.com/content/ek2q156624661848/ but I could only locate a $34 copy.

Comment: The facebook page says the journal was published first in 1933, but the article found by voix agrees with the original poster's date of 1930.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original article in German - W.A. Ambarzumjan, D.D. Iwanenko – Uber eine Folgerung der Diracschen Theorie der Protonen und Elektronen (On a Consequence of the Dirac Theory of Protons and Electrons) // Доклады Академии Наук СССР, сер. А (Doklady USSR Acad. Sci., Ser. A), Vol. 6, p. 153-155, 1930

[The article in Russian](http://www.ambartsumian.ru/dvd/Publications/Papers/1930DANSSSR___153A.pdf)  on  [this page](http://www.ambartsumian.ru/dvd/SciResults/mostimpsciresults_en.html)

Comment: Thankyou, I have asked for an english copy on the Library Stack: http://libraries.stackexchange.com/questions/691/how-to-find-an-old-soviet-physics-paper-in-english

Comment: @JoeHobbit, what is your  email? I can send a google translation of the paper to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one of [these](http://vambartsumian.org/index.php?id=128)? What's the title of the paper? I guess it could be the third one. I have no idea what the title means.

(If you need it translated, get the Google Chrome browser.) The papers are in English.

***Edit: Nevermind, these papers aren't relevant.

Comment: @Ruslan can you offer help? Here is a fellow who looks for a paper from 1930. Look what it is :*an old physics paper by Viktor Ambartsumyan and Dmitrii Ivanenko: Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR, ser. A, No. 6, p.153 (1930). It concerns the structure of the atomic nucleus and accurately predicted the neutron's existence. I have been unable to locate it online.*